# I added tailwindcss to vite+react+ts+sass,but it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, sass, tailwind-css, vite

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

index.tsx

```
...
import "./index.css";
<div className="p-xl text-center">1111</div>
...
```

but neither 'p-xl' nor 'text-center' work.only tailwindcss prefix css work.

Comment: Did you follow _all_ the steps in this guide? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it just now.
add it to tailwind.config.js

```
 content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```